# Numerical-Symbolical Integration (Calculus)

Tags: numerical-integration, calculus-and-analysis, symbolic

I created a simple numeric-symbolic integration. Here you can use symbolical and numerical techniques at the same time. You can also interpolate numerical integrals.

The problem with my function is the use of `TimeConstrained` for testing if the integral can be done fully symbolically. This wastes time; without it the result is much much faster.

How can it be optimized? Maybe there is some other implementation like this I haven't found?
Note: It can easily be extended to `Sum`-s, just exchange `Integrate` for `Sum` :)

```
Options@NSIntegrate = {
    InterpolationVariable -> {}
};

(* Linearity *)
NSIntegrate[f_ + g__, s_, options___] := NSIntegrate[f, s, options] + NSIntegrate[+g, s, options]
NSIntegrate[α_*f_, {x_, limits__}, options___] /; FreeQ[α, x] := α*NSIntegrate[f, {x, limits}, options]

(* Constant Function *)
NSIntegrate[α_, {x_, limits__}, options___] /; FreeQ[α, x] \[And] α =!= 1 := α*NSIntegrate[1, {x, limits}, options]

(* Exponentials *)
NSIntegrate[α_^(f_+g__), {x_, limits__}, options___] /; FreeQ[f, x] := α^f*NSIntegrate[α^g, {x, limits}, options]
NSIntegrate[α_^(f_+g__)*h_, {x_, limits__}, options___] /; FreeQ[f, x] := α^f*NSIntegrate[α^g*h, {x, limits}, options]

(* Some Basic Integrals - Polynomials *)
NSIntegrate[1, {x_, a_, b_}, ___] := b - a
NSIntegrate[x_, {x_, a_, b_}, ___] := (b^2 - a^2)/2
NSIntegrate[x_^-1, {x_, a_, b_}, ___] /; If[NumericQ@a \[And] NumericQ@b, Sign@a === Sign@b, True] \[And] a =!= b := Log[b/a]
NSIntegrate[x_^n_, {x_, a_, b_}, ___] /; n =!= -1 := (b^(n+1) - a^(n+1))/(n + 1)

(* Some Basic Integrals - Exponentials *)
NSIntegrate[α_^(A_*x_), {x_, a_, b_}, ___] /; α =!= 0 \[And] α =!= 1 := (α^(A*b) - α^(A*a))/(A*Log@α)
NSIntegrate[α_^x_, {x_, a_, b_}, ___] /; α =!= 0 \[And] α =!= 1 := (α^b - α^a)/Log@α
NSIntegrate[0^x_, s__, ___] := 0

(* Scaling and offset *)
NSIntegrate[f_[α_*x_ + β_, args___], {x_, a_, b_}, options___] /; (And @@ (FreeQ[#, x] & /@ Flatten@{args, α, β})) := 
    NSIntegrate[f[x, args]/α, {x, a*α + β, b*α + β}, options]
NSIntegrate[f_[α_*x_, args___], {x_, a_, b_}, options___] /; (And @@ (FreeQ[#, x] & /@ Flatten@{args, α})) := 
    NSIntegrate[f[x, args]/α, {x, a*α, b*α}, options]
NSIntegrate[f_[x_ + β_, args___], {x_, a_, b_}, options___] /; (And @@ (FreeQ[#, x] & /@ Flatten@{args, β})) := 
NSIntegrate[f[x, args], {x, a + β, b + β}, options]

(* Interpolation *)
NSIntegrate[f_, {x_, a_, b_}, options1___, InterpolationVariable -> varRange_List, options2___] /; Length@varRange != 0 := Module[{
    vars, range = varRange, table
    },
    If[Depth@varRange == 2, vars = varRange[[{1}]]; range = List@range, vars = varRange[[All, 1]]];

    table = Table[{vars, NSIntegrate[f, {x, a, b}, options1, options2]}, ##1] & @@ range;
    InterpolatingPolynomial[table, vars] /. s_Real :> Chop[s, 10^-6] // Expand
]

(* If not in database, use NIntegrate *)
NSIntegrate[f_, s:{x_, a_, b_}, opts___] /; ExpandAll@f =!= f := NSIntegrate[ExpandAll@f, s, opts]
NSIntegrate[f_, s:{x_, a_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ}, opts___] := NIntegrate[f, s, opts]
```

*Usage:

```
NSIntegrate[Cos[a*x], {x, 0, 1}, InterpolationVariable -> {a, 1, 5, 1/2}]
```

`InterpolationVariable` work just like in a `Table`. In case or more than 1 interpolation use in the form `{{a, 1, 5}, {b, 1, 10, 0.3}}`

** Added `(* Scaling and offset *)` section.

Comment: "The problem with my function is the use of `TimeConstrained` for testing if the integral can be done fully symbolically." - unless you want to go through all the trouble of reimplementing the Risch algorithm, I'm not sure you can do better...

Comment: Yeay, I thought so too, to re-implement all Mathematica is waste of time, it's better just to use interpolation and add some simple rules.
I wanted also to make `NSIntegrate` multidimensional, but this seams a litte bit hard